# Create 3D Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create a 3D-Graph. Therefore I want to put 3 calculated values, let's call them A,B and C, into an np.array.
It should somehow look like this:

[A_1, B_1, C_1],
[A_2, B_2, C_2],
.
.
.
[A_N, B_N, C_N]

How can I do this? I tried using in a for loop (the foor loop calculates the values of A,B,C)

```
E = np.array(A,B,C)
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
import numpy as np
A = [1,2,3]
B = [4,5,6]
C = [7,8,9]
array = np.array([A,B,C])
```

```
print(array)
```

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

```
print(array.shape)
```

```
(3, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking for but one thing you could take a look at is the following

https://repl.it/join/amkbnhhs-henride

here is the code

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array((1,2,3))
b = np.array((2,3,4))
c = np.array((2,3,4))
print(np.dstack((a,b,c)))
```